# Error running e2e tests on flipper

Tags: ink, substrate-contracts-node

I have the substrate-contracts-node running and I run the following command on the [flipper](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/tree/main/flipper) contract:

```
cargo test --features e2e-tests
```

Results in the following error:

```
running 4 tests
test flipper::tests::default_works ... ok
test flipper::tests::it_works ... ok
test flipper::e2e_tests::default_works ... FAILED
test flipper::e2e_tests::it_works ... FAILED

failures:

---- flipper::e2e_tests::default_works stdout ----
thread 'flipper::e2e_tests::default_works' panicked at 'error on ws request `contracts_instantiate`: Rpc(ClientError(Call(Custom(ErrorObject { code: InternalError, message: "Unknown error occurred", data: Some(RawValue("Client(Execution(RuntimePanicked(\"Bad input data provided to instantiate: unexpected first byte decoding Option\")))")) }))))', /Users/bruno/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ink_e2e-4.0.1/src/xts.rs:237:17

---- flipper::e2e_tests::it_works stdout ----
thread 'flipper::e2e_tests::it_works' panicked at 'error on ws request `contracts_instantiate`: Rpc(ClientError(Call(Custom(ErrorObject { code: InternalError, message: "Unknown error occurred", data: Some(RawValue("Client(Execution(RuntimePanicked(\"Bad input data provided to instantiate: unexpected first byte decoding Option\")))")) }))))', /Users/bruno/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ink_e2e-4.0.1/src/xts.rs:237:17
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace


failures:
    flipper::e2e_tests::default_works
    flipper::e2e_tests::it_works

test result: FAILED. 2 passed; 2 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 1.04s
```

```
cargo-contract-contract 2.1.0-unknown-aarch64-apple-darwin
stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.68.0 (2c8cc3432 2023-03-06)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you run [the latest](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/releases/tag/v0.24.0) release of `substrate-contracts-node` and have it installed in PATH. You do not need to run it in the background, E2E tests will automatically start the node for each test independently.

Comment: This is correct. I ran: `cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git --tag v0.24.0` and re-ran the e2e tests and it worked.